# Standard error for sum of random variables

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, auc, sum

I am conducting an analysis of pharmacokinetics data in which I have plasma concentration of drug for different dosage groups. In this way, the area under the concentration-dose curve is computed as

$$
AUC=\sum[({\bar c}_i + {\bar c}_{i+1})\times(d_{i+1}-d_i)/2] 
$$

In which ${\bar c}_i$ and $d_i$ are the mean plasma concentration and dose of $i$th dosage group separately. In this case, I assume that ${\bar c}_i$ are independent random variables that follow the normal distributions $N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ and $d_i$ are constants. I want to estimate the 95% confidence interval of AUC. For this purpose, I need the standard error for sum of random variables. I am not sure whether the following formula is correct
$$
E(AUC)=\sum[(\mu_i+\mu_{i+1})\times(d_{i+1}-d_i)/2]
$$
$$
VAR(AUC)=\sum\{(\sigma_i^2+\sigma_{i+1}^2)\times(\frac{d_{i+1}-d_i}{2})^2\}
$$
Any information on the formula for SE for sum of random variables, or any links which gives an idea is highly appreciated!

Comment: Do not know where you are getting AUC$=\sum[({\bar c}_i + {\bar c}_{i+1})\times(d_{i+1}-d_i)/2]$ from. If you have enough data of that type, plot AUC as a histogram to see what it looks like. To find the mean AUC of a series of AUC values, just average the values, and for variance just find the square of the standard deviation of that series of AUC values. If you have enough data, the confidence intervals are computed as quantiles. How much data do you have?